# Angular: How to project any content into a dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-library

**What's most importantly needed:** For data from the parent `top-navbar` to be passed to the child that's being projected. In this case, that's `custom-component`. It' doesn't need to be passed via the `data` input value as shown below, and can instead get the configuration from the same service call the `top-navbar` gets its data from.

---

We have a reusable navbar component that gets its configuration from a service and want to add the ability for the consuming app to add a dropdown with any custom HTML in it. Here's an example of how it would work preferably:

```html
<top-navbar 
    (onRouteClick)="routeClicked($event)">
    <div #carDropdown> 
        // Some custom html
        <custom-component 
            [data]="needsDataPassedToTopNavbarConfig">
        </custom-component>
    </div>
</top-navbar>
```

Data below is handed to the top-navbar component through an observable on a navbar service. The config would look something like:

```
 menuItems = [
    {
      displayText: "States",
      pageTitle: "US States",
      routePath: "statelist",
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      displayText: "Car List",
      pageTitle: "Cars",
      routePath: "Cars",
      isActive: false,
      dropdown: 'carDropdown',
      hasChildren: [{
        displayText: 'Ford',
        pageTitle: 'Ford Cars',
        routePath: 'ford'
      }, {
        displayText: 'Volvo',
        pageTitle: 'Volvo Cars',
        routePath: 'volvo'
      }]
    }
]
```

---

Im sorry I don't have an example of what I have tried yet, I just don't even know where to look and even appreciate just being pointed in the right direction, or to be notified whether this is even possible or not.

Comment: Why not create a top-nav-menu component that takes the list of menu items and does recursion to display nested items?

Comment: @Rana_S Im not sure Im aware of what you mean, but the main thing is the content of the dropdown can be unknown so we didn't want to use any sort of configuration object for it since that would limit what we could put in it

Comment: I don’t think I got your question right. So you need a way to pass the config data to the current child component?